# Are there non-static and static areas in the method area of JVM memory?

Tags: java, jvm

I heard that there are non-static and static areas in JVM memory in a lecture course, but I can't find any information about the two areas of the method area of JVM memory.

Do non-static and static areas exist in the method area?

I think they must be because when the program needs some non-static method, JVM has to load the method on the non-static area of the method area and it has to be efficiently deleted if the non-static method is not used anymore by heap area or stack area.

Comment: Methods are only removed if the entire class that contains them is unloaded (not usual in most programs).

Comment: The method area is a logical concept, specified in [JVMS §2.5.4.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4). Since it doesn’t say that there were a “non-static area” and “static area”, there aren’t. Basically, it’s only named there, to specify that implementations can implement it however they want. Given, how many questions center about this, it seems, it was a historical mistake to ever give that thing a name.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be conflating storage requirements for methods (code) and fields (data).

Non-static fields are represented in the heap node of each **object** that has those fields. Naturally, when the object is deleted, all of its fields go away as well.

Static fields are represented in (typically) a heap node that is associated with the **class** that declares the fields. Normally, this node lives for the lifetime of the JVM. However, if the associated class is *unloaded*, then the node is (notionally) eligible for garbage collection.

Whether the former and latter nodes are in the same area of the heap is ... implementation-dependent.

I suspect that this is what the lecture was talking about. (However, it is not entirely clear without actually seeing/hearing what the lecture material says.

---

> Are there non-static and static areas in the method area of JVM memory?

Basically, no.

The memory that holds the code of methods is associated with the class and has the same lifetime<sup>1</sup> as the class (see above). Therefore the code for static and non-static (instance) methods can be (and is) stored the same way.

The area in which the code is stored is also implementation-dependent.  However, for recent JVMs methods are held in metaspace ... which is not strictly part of the Java heap.

A final note: you don't need to know the precise details of this unless you are or plan to be an OpenJDK developer. And if you do need (or want) to know the precise details ... look at the source code.  But beware that it could take you weeks to get your head around it, depending on how experienced you are with this kind of thing.

---

<sup>1 - This is an oversimplification. In some contexts, the JIT compiler may recompile native code. When that happens, the JVM will reallocate the memory blocks that hold a method's native code. However, it is all taken care of ...</sup>